# Implement if else statement in MS SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using Sql Server 2008 r2:

```
begin

    insert tablename1(param1, param2)values(@param1,@param2)

    if(@param1=="2222"  && @param2<5)

    set @param2 = @param2 + 1

    update tablename2 set param2=@param2 where param1=@param1

end

end
```

How to implement sql procedure like this.

Comment: What is the question and what is the problem?

Comment: @Panagiotis: user1663380 seems to be unable to find the correct syntax for T-SQL `IF`.

Comment: Pressing F1 with the cursor over the `IF` keyword will solve this. Or simply reading the documentation. Or googling for said documentation

Comment: Are you asking "How do I update a table based on data in another table?"

Answer (score 2):

T-SQL has an [`if-else` statement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx). For the conditional, use the same syntax you would use for a `WHERE` clause, e.g., `AND` instead of `&&`, `=` instead of `==` and single quotes for strings. `IF` expects a single statement; if you want to execute a block of code, wrap it in `BEGIN`...`END`.

In your case, the code could look like this:

```
IF @param1 = '2222' AND @param2 < 5
BEGIN
    ...
END
```

PS: When searching for SQL Server syntax elements, include `t-sql` in your keywords. For example, a Google search for `t-sql if` yields the description of the SQL Server IF-ELSE-Syntax as the first hit.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the question that you're asking is, How do I update `tablename2` based on the values in `tablename1`?

```
UPDATE t2
SET t2.param2= t1.param2 + 1
FROM tablename1 t1
JOIN tablename2 t2 ON t1.param1 = t2.param1
WHERE (t1.param1 = '2222' AND t1.param2 < 5)
```

This query updates `tablename2` when there is a record in `tablename1` with `param1='2222'` and `param2<5`.

I setup some test data and a before and after query using [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a29866/2) (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a29866/2).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `@param1` is a string and `@param2` a number, try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[procedure_name]
@param1     varchar(50),
@param2     int
AS

begin
    insert into tablename1(param1, param2) values(@param1,@param2)

    if @param1='2222' and @param2 < 5
    begin
        set @param2 = @param2 + 1
        update tablename2 set param2=@param2 where param1=@param1
    end
end
```